# pymongo: search dict OR operation

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using below code trying to get all the records that, the "user_name" field OR the "text" field contains the specified keyword, it looks like pymongo treat the operation to be AND, how to specify the pymongo to treat it the "OR" operation?

```
search_dict = {}

text_regex = ".*" + key + ".*";
text_reg = re.compile(text_regex,re.IGNORECASE)
search_dict["text"] = text_reg

user_name_regex = ".*" + key + ".*";
user_name_reg = re.compile(user_name_regex,re.IGNORECASE)
search_dict["user_name"] = user_name_reg

records = gLife_Article_Collection.find(search_dict)
```

Answer (score 4):

@qiao is correct the `$or` syntax is right heres a full example:

```
import re
from pymongo import Connection
connection = Connection()
db = connection.test_database
db.regex_test.drop()

# Create some sample docs
db.regex_test.save({"user_name": "Rozza", "text": "Writing an example for Bin Chen based on qiao's answer"})
db.regex_test.save({"user_name": "qiao", "text": "Answering Bin Chen's question"})
db.regex_test.save({"user_name": "Bin Chen", "text": "Reading rozza's answer"})

# Do a regex $or query simple example
search_dict = {"$or": [
    {"user_name": {"$regex": "^Rozza"}}, 
    {"text": {"$regex": "rozza"}}
]}
assert db.regex_test.find(search_dict).count() == 2

# Do a regex $or query with re.compile
search_dict = {"$or": [
    {"user_name": re.compile("*.Rozza.*", re.IGNORECASE)}, 
    {"text": re.compile("*.Rozza.*", re.IGNORECASE)}
]}
assert db.regex_test.find(search_dict).count() == 2
```

Comment: Really appreciate your effort :)

Comment: No worries! Lets hope @Ben Chen will mark as answered.  Should help any others that have problems with regexes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The special key `$or` will let you do logic combinations, see the official MongoDB document: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or

```
search_dict = {'$or': [{'text': text_reg}, {'user_name': user_name_reg}]}
records = gLife_Article_Collections.find(search_dict)
```

Comment: Did you just copy and pasted my code above? I made a typo, `username` instead of `user_name`. Fixed it now.

Comment: No I didn't, the typing is correct, your solution just can't work... I don't know why.